# mutt destroys allignment of file alligned by column command unix

Tags: unix, mutt

I have a well aligned csv file.

- That was generated using the command
  `column -s, -t < myFile >myFormattedFile`. It looks as expected.
- Now I want the same to be displayed in gmail body. And I use command `mutt my@email -s my_subject < myFormattedFile`
- However in gmail formatting gets destroyed. Searching on the web I found that i can set `set text_flowed=yes` in the muttrc. But even that doesnt work.
  -If I attach the file using `-a` option in mutt, then formatting is preserved (opening the attachment). Also note that if the attached file given the name myFormattedFile.csv then google opens it with spreadsheet with destroyed formatting. This last point is just my additional observation.

Comment: If i attach the file, then formatting is preserved. But is there a way to preserve formatting in "Body" of the mail. The muttrc has editor=vim, but if i open it in vim, its displayed properly.

Comment: are you sure the lost formatting isn't just the use of variable-width character sets on your screen? Is the default font something like Verdanna? Does changing the default font to fixed-width font help? (Not sure how to do this). You could see the effect I'm talking about by pasting in 1 line of your data (preferably less than 80 chars worth) at the bottom of this message (separated by blank lines, top and bottom). Then paste the same line but add 4 spaces at the front, so S.O. uses 'code' formatting (which is fixed-width font). Good luck.